# SSRS - : How to make a conditional formatting for matrix by group?

Tags: ssrs, powerbi, report

I currently have a report produces a matrix, displayed per user group.  (1 user group per page, with 35 user groups/pages)

I want to highlight the row in pink in this condition:

```
=IIf(Fields!CountFailures.Value>=1,"Pink","White")
```

However, it is not showing any colour.  Please help! (I am using PowerBI Report Builder... should be same as SSRS)

Answer (score 1):

If you are formatting cells based on group totals and not a row value, you need to use an aggregate and indicate the correct row group scope.  In this sample, "UserName" is the name of the row group scope on the Row Groups section of the Grouping pane

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!CountFailures.Value, "UserName") >=1, "Pink", "White")
```

[image: Design]

[image: Run]